# How to match exact Search in Solr with space

Tags: java, solr

How to search a part of the word when space is present between two words. My query this like below

```
/select?q=*:*&fq=pageType:program&fl=programLocation&rows=100&fq=programLocation:"Mohali"
```

The result I am getting is as below

```
"response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "programLocation":["Mohali"]},
      {
        "programLocation":["Mohali"]},
      {
        "programLocation":["Mohali and Hyderabad"]}]
```

I want to retrieve only "Mohali", but now I am getting both  "Mohali" and "Mohali and Hyderabad". How to form a query to only fetch Mohali?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `string` as `fieldtype` for your field `programLocation`.

Apply the String as `fieldtype` and reindex the data.

```
<field name="programLocation" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

`String` stores the word/sentence as an exact string without performing any tokenization on it.
Its useful in cases for storing exact matches, e.g, for faceting, sorting.

Opposite of `string` type is `text`.
`Text` does the tokenization of data, performs processing such as lower-casing etc. It is helpful in case when we want to match part of a sentence.

If you want achieve the lowercase search then use the below fieldtype for you field.

```
<fieldType name="forExactMatch" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
             input string is preserved as a single token
          -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
             when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
          -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

If you have spaces the you can also use the below filter after the lowercase filter factory.

```
<filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
```

Then your field defination will look like below

```
<field name="programLocation" type="forExactMatch" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For an exact match with lucene search in java

`?q="Your search"~0`

Your can play with the integer to define the max distance between words

`?q="Your search"~2`

Exemple : "This is an awesome exemple of exact match"

- `?q="awesome exemple"~0` will match
- `?q="awesome exact match"~0` won't match
- `?q="awesome exact match"~2` will match